# How to render a Rails view to a string I can use within a model method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, string, templates, render

Let's say I have a view called `/users/recipes.haml`

```
- @user.recipes.each do |recipe|
  %p= recipe.name
```

I need to build out this view as a simple string, to inject it into something. How can I do this from within a model?

Basically, how can I pass a few variables to a template, and capture the result as a simple string variable?

Answer (score 2):

You can do following to render template and store into string:

```
ActionController::Base.new.render_to_string(:template => "/users/recipes.haml", :locals => {:@user => user})
```